# 3 way merge sort implementation array index issue

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement 3way merge sort but there is an obstacle i am stuck with. 2 Way merge sort is simple but when you try 3way, during division of the array into 3 parts. Before sorting i just try to implement the appropriate splitting and array addressing. when i run this code below

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  mergeSort(arr1,0,8);
  mergeSort(arr1,1,9);
  return 0;

}

void mergeSort(int* arr,int min,int max)
{

  int mid1=(2*min + max)/3;
  int mid2=max-(max/3);
  std::cout <<min<<"-"<< mid1<<"-"<<mid2<<"-"<<max<< std::endl;
}
```

I get;

```
0-2-6-8
1-3-6-9
```

when i call mergesort i call it with mergesort(array,min,max) and so does it recursively.
If index starts with 0 it misses 1element at the middle. Should i use 1 as minimum since i divide the array 3way? Or is there a better stable, sensible way i should learn?

Comment: Maybe you can try making your 'max' exclusive. So you will call mergeSort(arr1, 0, 9) instead. mid1 should be 3, mid2 should be 6. So your ranges for the next level would be 0-3(exclude), 3-6(exclude), 6-9(exclude) which are all equal

Comment: Just a small note, for `mid2` you need to use `max-(max-min)/3`. Right now, in your code, no matter what array length is, `mid2` is going to be two thirds of the last index.

Comment: triple_r i still couldn't manage to properly address and split the thirds of the array, could you give me some more advice?